# Could someone explain this code to me - traversing keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, fasta

I have this code that I cobbled together based on some posts on here. It takes a FASTA file (file that features DNA sequences) and finds sequences whose molecular weights are within the given weight range. To do this, it uses a dictionary resulting from a previously-built function, seq_ID_and_weight, which (as its name suggests) outputs the ID of sequences in the file and the minimum and maximum values of their molecular weights (sequences can be ambiguous, so there are many possible weights).

The below function does what I need it to do, but I'm not actually sure how.

```
def find_sequence(file_name, min_weight, max_weight):
        ID_list=[] # Initialize a list to store seq IDs
        with open (file_name) as file:
            dictionary = (seq_ID_and_weight(file_name))
            for k,v in dictionary.items(): # This function lets you traverse the dictionary
                for i in range(min(2,len(v))):
                    if v[i]>min_weight and v[i]<max_weight: # If value is within given range, append the sequence_id to list.
                        ID_list.append(k)
                        break
        return ID_list
```

I understand up until the "for i in range" line. I know that line is there because I have to deal with keys that have two values as well as keys that have only one. But what does the min function do? And why am I using i as a variable?

Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I am new to Python.

Comment: Consider the result of `min(2, len(v))`. If `len(v)` is smaller than 2, the result is `len(v)`. Otherwise it's 2. This value is then passed to `range`.

Answer (score 1):

Python `min()` returns the smallest item from an iterable object or two or more arguments. Here is the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

`i` is short for representing the index value within the range from 0 to the value of `min(2,len(v))`, and is used as the index within the dictionary value `v` (assuming it's an iterable object)